# Cloning something inside a singleton object

Tags: java, singleton

Maybe I'm just having a blackout but I cant find a feasible way to resolve my problem.

I have a singleton object of `Class A` containing an `ArrayList<Item>`. In `Class C` I need a specific `Item` of `ArrayList<Item>` (clone it). While `ArrayList<Item>` should be unchanged, I need to apply some modifications to the `Item` in `Class C`. I tried implementing Cloneable in `Class Item` like this:

```js
public class Item implements Cloneable {

  private ArrayList<String> mSize = new ArrayList<>();

  protected Object clone() throws CloneNotSupportedException {
    return super.clone();
  }

  public void modifySomething() {
  mSize.clear();
  }

}
```

Afterwards I wanted to get the `Item` like this:

```js
class C {

 void foo() {

  Item item = null;

  try {
   item = (Item) A.getInstance().getItems().get(0).clone();
   item.modifySomething();
  } catch (CloneNotSupportedException e) {
   e.printStackTrace();
  }

 }
}
```

**The problem is that the `Item item` also gets modified in the singleton object.**

***Q:*** Did i take the wrong approach to this? How can I get the desired behaviour?

Comment: An MVCE would be very much appreciated. At this point there's no telling where the gotcha is. `Object.clone()` returns a shallow copy, so maybe that has something to do with it?

Comment: Perhaps you can post a [mcve] that includes what `modifysomething` actually does. If `Item` contains mutable objects, then your `clone()` method might be too simplistic.

Comment: Also note that this has **nothing** to do with singletons or lists or what not. When trying to write up that minimal example, focus on just that: you have a class with a clone() method, and manipulating a cloned object somhow changes the original object. That alone is at the heart of your question, and anything else is noise that only adds complexity for no reason.

Comment: @Robby Cornelissen @khelwood : added some extra code, hope this clarifies my point. Yes, `Item` contains mutable objects.
@GhostCat thanks for the hint. As I said, I'm kinda confused.

Comment: Yup, it's a shallow copy problem. You'll have to explicitly clone the `ArrayList`.

Comment: basically a duplicate of:  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/869033/how-do-i-copy-an-object-in-java

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here:

```
protected Object clone() throws CloneNotSupportedException {
  return super.clone();
}
```

That is basically a "no op". It does **not** magically copy the content of your list into a new one. And just for the record: for *any* method, it is really pointless to *override*, but to then only call the super method implementation. Then you could as well: just not override that method.

So, either use a different mechanism, or *really* overwrite that method, with custom content to create a new List. Otherwise your clone and the original Item object operate on the **same** list instance.

Answer (score 2):

What happens is, the clone it is not a "deep" clone, you still have referencing the same:

```
private ArrayList<String> mSize = new ArrayList<>();
```

inside you Cloned object. It if was a cloned object with no Collection attributes, it would work fine for you.

Apache Commons Lang has SerializationUtils#clone, which performs a deep copy when all classes in the object graph implement the Serializable interface.

```
item = (Item) SerializationUtils.clone(A.getInstance().getItems().get(0));
```

Comment: Also, changing Item to implements Serializable.

Comment: This is the library from apache: https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.commons/commons-lang3